# How to properly check a variable for null

Tags: c#, null

[Screenshot of the Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qOmz.png)

```
Employee projectManager = project.OwnerSolution.Employees.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == project.ProjectManager);
_lblProjectManagerValue.Text = projectManager != null ? projectManager.DisplayName : "Mitarbeiter nicht gefunden";
```

I am wondering how I could do a null check in C#. I was expecting the runtime to jump into the else branch because the variable `projectManager` is null, but thats not the case for some reason.

`project.Employees` does return a null reference.

Comment: Is an exception actually thrown by your code or just in the debugger?

Comment: That also happens when I am starting the exe (CTRL+F5).

Comment: The code you posted and the code in the exception image are different. Have you tried the code you posted?

Comment: Yes, I changed it afterwards. Both checks are not working for some reason. That happens to me the first time in two years. :(

Comment: you have added statement `projectManager = null` right before if - that is why it is null

Comment: @ChiragRupani Those are debugger hints, not code.

Comment: Try a clean/rebuild-all. I'm assuming that this code is not multi-threaded where something could be setting that project manager to null between the check and the assignment?

Comment: @RonBeyer I have already stepped over it. The variable gets assigned null but when I do the next step I get an exception. Threads are not used in the whole project. I tried already a clean build, but that shouldnt really matter as I added the code and since that build the code is throwing a null reference exception.

Comment: There is something odd going on. Why does your `if` condition have a squiggly line, please scroll over it and see what the warning is. Also why is the `else` block greyed out (is that a new visual studio feature)?

Comment: You say "I added the code and since that build the code is throwing a null reference exception".  What code did you add, this or some other?  If something else, can you show us?

Comment: @CodingYoshi that is a feature of ReSharper. The green Line means that the if-statement can be converted into ? operator.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the `if` statement and then see if the breakpoint is hit. If the source code is different than the compiled version, you will see a warning on the breakpoint at runtime and the breakpoint will not be hit.

Comment: The code does not differ. If it would then the code would not exist. This is fresh added code. The Method is completely new.

Comment: When I change the statement to `_lblProjectManagerValue.Text = projectManager == null ? projectManager.DisplayName : "Mitarbeiter nicht gefunden";` then the code is fine for some reason

Answer (score 1):

If any part of your list of queries can be null, instead of manually checking every single one in a big long list of `if` statements just use a [Null-Conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

```
var projectManagerName = project?.OwnerSolution?.Employees?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == project?.ProjectManager)?.DisplayName;
_lblProjectManagerValue.Text = projectManagerName ?? "Mitarbeiter nicht gefunden";
```

Comment: Do you see a long list of `if` conditions in OPs code or question? This does not answer the question.

Comment: That is not really a solution. There seems to be a bug that the null check is not executed properly and I have no Idea what to do.

Comment: Sorry just updated it I forgot to edit your line 2 should be fine now

Comment: There would be a long list of ifs if the code was fixed for null checks. And how does this not answer the question?